# Visual Studio code Command not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am new to VS Code extension development.

I followed this document to create a java script based extension

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension

I pressed F5, it opened the extension window and when i pressed the 'Hello World' in the command palette. I get an error

`Command 'Hello World' resulted in an error (command 'sometext.helloworld' not found)`

It seems the text 'sometext.helloworld' is different from what is mentioned in 'helloworld.helloworld' in package.json below.

I am on VS Code 1.73.0.

My package.json

```json
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "displayName": "HelloWorld",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.76.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "helloworld.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.76.0",
    "@types/glob": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.53.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.53.0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "glob": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.2.3"
  }
}
```

extension.ts

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "helloworld" is now active!');

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.helloWorld', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from HelloWorld!');
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

Comment: where in your workspace can you find the text `sometext`, use VSC find in files

Comment: it seems there was another extension installed with hello world... i uninstalled that...and followed the steps afresh ...but i don't the extension in my  dev host